# With Python multiprocessing cannot share LDAP object to subprocesses

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-ldap, python-multiprocessing

I am going to have one subprocess to send LDAP queries and other subprocess to retrieve the responses.
There is a problem with sharing the LDAP object between both processes. Could someone point me to a solution?

```
import ldap
from multiprocessing import Process


def send_ldap(ldap_conn):
    print ldap_conn

def receive_ldap(ldap_conn):
    print ldap_conn

def main():
    ldap_conn = ldap.initialize('ldap://abc:12345')
    ldap_sender = Process(target=send_ldap, args=(ldap_conn,))
    ldap_receiver = Process(target=receive_ldap, args=(ldap_conn,))
    ldap_sender.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The error is with the pickle module:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "t.py", line 16, in main
    ldap_sender.start()
  File "c:\python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 130, in start
    self._popen = Popen(self)
  File "c:\python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 277, in __init__
    dump(process_obj, to_child, HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
  File "c:\python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 199, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "c:\python27\lib\pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "c:\python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "c:\python27\lib\pickle.py", line 419, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "c:\python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "c:\python27\lib\pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "c:\python27\lib\pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "c:\python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "c:\python27\lib\pickle.py", line 548, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "c:\python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "c:\python27\lib\pickle.py", line 725, in save_inst
    save(stuff)
  File "c:\python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "c:\python27\lib\pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "c:\python27\lib\pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "c:\python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "c:\python27\lib\pickle.py", line 725, in save_inst
    save(stuff)
  File "c:\python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "c:\python27\lib\pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "c:\python27\lib\pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "c:\python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\pickle.py", line 396, in save_reduce
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 381, in main
save(cls)
      File "c:\python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
self = load(from_parent)
      File "c:\python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1378, in load
f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "c:\python27\lib\pickle.py", line 748, in save_global
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "c:\python27\lib\pickle.py", line 858, in load
    (obj, module, name))
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'thread.lock'>: it's not found as thread.lock
dispatch[key](self)
  File "c:\python27\lib\pickle.py", line 880, in load_eof
    raise EOFError
EOFError
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `ldap_conn` object is not picklable, which is required to send it between processes in Windows. It's not picklable because it uses some non-picklable `threading.Lock` objects internally. The library actually claims to provide a [`ReconnectLDAPObject`](http://www.python-ldap.org/doc/html/ldap.html#ldap.ReconnectLDAPObject) that's supposed to be picklable, but it's broken and isn't picklable, either. We can fix this, though, by subclass it and fixing the bug (it misses removing one of the internal locks prior to pickling):

```
from ldap.ldapobject import ReconnectLDAPObject
from multiprocessing import Process
import ldap

class PicklableLDAPObject(ReconnectLDAPObject):
    def __getstate__(self):
        d = ReconnectLDAPObject.__getstate__(self)
        del d['_reconnect_lock']
        return d

    def __setstate__(self, d):
        self._reconnect_lock = ldap.LDAPLock(desc='reconnect lock within %s' % (repr(self)))
        ReconnectLDAPObject.__setstate__(self, d)

def send_ldap(ldap_conn):
    print ldap_conn

def receive_ldap(ldap_conn):
    print ldap_conn

def main():
    #ldap_conn = ldap.initialize('ldap://abc:12345')
    ldap_conn = PicklableLDAPObject('ldap://abc:12345')
    ldap_sender = Process(target=send_ldap, args=(ldap_conn,))
    ldap_receiver = Process(target=receive_ldap, args=(ldap_conn,))
    ldap_sender.start()
```

Now the object will pickle fine, which means it should be useable for `multiprocessing` purposes.

Comment: I've also [filed a bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/python-ldap/bugs/64/) for the issue with `ReconnectLDAPObject` not being picklable.

Comment: I'm having this problem, except with a custom class I've defined rather than an LDAP object. My class contains a bunch of different data objects that need to be accessed by the sub-process, including a multiprocessing.lock, which is integral to the operation of the two threads. Is there any solution for me? Can I just pass handles to each individual object that needs to be accessed? (I don't really understand why/how pickle is used here, nor am I familiar with LDAP)